# How to gracefully shutdown chained goroutines in an idiomatic way

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

Creating multiple goroutines which will have nested goroutines while processing in a multilevel manner (Imagine a tree of goroutines each level can have many leaves).

What is the idiomatic way to **gracefully shutdown these goroutines in order** and wait for them to come back? Order is the bottom top (deepest child first) and also assume I dont know how many goroutines I will launch beforehand (dynamic).

the example below just gracefully shuts them down in an **non ordered** manner.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)

    //level1
    go func() {
        fmt.Println("level1 started")
        //level2
        go func() {
            fmt.Println("level2 started")

            //level3
            go func() {
                fmt.Println("level3 started")
                select {
                case <-ctx.Done():
                    fmt.Println("Done called on level3")
                case <-time.After(5* time.Second):
                    fmt.Println("After called on level3")
                }

            }()
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                fmt.Println("Done called on level2")
            case <-time.After(7* time.Second):
                fmt.Println("After called on level2")
            }

        }()
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Println("Done called on level1")
        case <-time.After(10* time.Second):
            fmt.Println("After called on level1")
        }


    }()
    time.Sleep(1*time.Second)
    cancel()
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
}
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend asssessing your design to find a way to eliminate the requirement that they shut down in order. You should only need to synchronize concurrent data access, and that only rarely (when they absolutely must share memory). A need to shut down goroutines in order implies a faulty design.

Answer (score 4):

To wait for a group of goroutines, [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) is the idiomatic solution. You can add 1 to its counter when you launch a new goroutine ([`WaitGroup.Add()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup.Add)), and the goroutine can signal that it's done with [`WaitGroup.Done()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup.Done). The parent goroutine may call [`WaitGroup.Wait()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup.Wait) to wait all its children to finish.

You may do the same on each level. Create a `WaitGroup` on each level where child goroutines are launched, and only return when `Wait()` of that goroutine returns.

Here's how it's applied on your example:

```
ctx := context.Background()
ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)

//level1
wg1 := &sync.WaitGroup{}
wg1.Add(1)
go func() {
    defer wg1.Done()
    fmt.Println("level1 started")
    //level2
    wg2 := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg2.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg2.Done()
        fmt.Println("level2 started")

        //level3
        wg3 := &sync.WaitGroup{}
        wg3.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg3.Done()
            fmt.Println("level3 started")
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                fmt.Println("Done called on level3")
            case <-time.After(5 * time.Second):
                fmt.Println("After called on level3")
            }
            fmt.Println("Level 3 ended.")
        }()

        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Println("Done called on level2")
        case <-time.After(7 * time.Second):
            fmt.Println("After called on level2")
        }
        wg3.Wait()
        fmt.Println("Level 2 ended.")
    }()

    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("Done called on level1")
    case <-time.After(10 * time.Second):
        fmt.Println("After called on level1")
    }
    wg2.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Level 1 ended.")
}()

time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
cancel()
wg1.Wait()
fmt.Println("Main ended.")
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hXJjES-7bYE)):

```
level1 started
level2 started
level3 started
Done called on level1
Done called on level3
Level 3 ended.
Done called on level2
Level 2 ended.
Level 1 ended.
Parent ended.
```

What's important from the output:

```
Level 3 ended.
Level 2 ended.
Level 1 ended.
Main ended.
```

Levels end in descending level order (from bottom-up), closing with `"Main ended."`.

Comment: oh lol... I just skimmed through the actual question and answered to the question in the title :facepalm:

Answer (score 0):

One possible, also I'd say idiomatic, way to do this is by passing a channel of `strict{}`. Whenever you'd like the said goroutine to terminate just write an empty struct to this channel: `shutdown <- struct{}{}`. This should do the job.
Alternatively you could close the channel, you'll recognise  this by having `false` as the second return value of `<-`, but I'd suggest using this only if you need to share this channel with multiple goroutines. In general I find this approach a bit shoddy and error prone.

On a side note: the way the shutdown of the goroutines is done in your example, once the context has been cancelled, all goroutines will return. Don't know whether this has much benefit in the general case. Maybe in your case it does.